# Как сохранять положение кнопок навигации при нажатии?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

у меня есть навигационное меню,
html:

```
<header class="scrmenu">
        <span class="menu-logo">beans</span>
        <nav class="scrollmenu">
            <menu class="menuScroll">
                
                    <a href="portfolio.html" class="navBar">Портфолио</a>
                
                    <a href="price.html" class="navBar">Стоимость</a>
                
                    <a href="about.html" class="navBar">Студия</a>
                
                    <a href="index.html" class="active">Экспресс-дизайн</a>
                
                    <a href="" class="navBar rightNav">Заказать&nbsp;дизайн</a>
                
            </menu>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

css:

```
   .menuScroll {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
  }
  
header {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    /* max-width: 95%; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 18px;
    /* z-index: 2222; */
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 30px;
}
nav {
    margin: 0 ;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
nav::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}

.navBar {
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 300ms ease-in-out, color 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out, color 300ms ease-in-out;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
   max-height: 45px;
}

.navBar:hover {
    background-color: #000; 
    color: white;
}
```

можно ли в мобильной версии при нажатии на кнопки навигации сохранять их положение при перезагрузке страницы?

Comment: не совсем понял суть задания, можно подробней описать что нужно в итоге получить?

Comment: в мобильной версии навигационное меню прокручивается горизонтально, при перезагрузке страницы навигационное меню возвращается в начальное положение, можно ли сохранять положение прокрутки при перезагрузке?

Comment: да, используйте html anchor (якоря)